# Can't compare strings by alphabetical order

Tags: c#, string, string-comparison, alphabetical

My DB stores keys by alphabetical order:

```
-MmNI8oyb2QE_9V0WdaX \\1st (oldest)
-MmOAFDL9ZPD1gx4SjEU \\2nd
-MmPtIJ1LpFTRbweNWvD \\3rd
-MmPtd0IMuNIEYaPYPgZ \\4th (newest)
```

The sorting order on this list is correct [you can check here that it's an alphabetical order](https://onlinestringtools.com/sort-strings). 1st string is the smallest, then 2nd, 3rd, and 4th.

I would like to compare every two strings from that list, and get the correct results like the order of that specific list, so if I compare the 4th string with the 3rd one, I'll receive a result that 4th is bigger than the 3rd.

What I tried so far: using `string.Compare`, however it doesn't work right for my specific list
the results I received weren't consistent

```
string first="-MmNI8oyb2QE_9V0WdaX";
string second="-MmOAFDL9ZPD1gx4SjEU";
string third="-MmPtIJ1LpFTRbweNWvD";
string fourth="-MmPtd0IMuNIEYaPYPgZ";
string.Compare(third,fourth) //output: 1
string.Compare(second,third) //output: -1
string.Compare(first,second) //output: -1
```

(Output should all be either "1"  or "-1". because my list is sorted)
What function should I use instead of comparing the strings? I also tried `string.Compare(3rd,4th,false)` an overload which compares by the case but it didn't help, my guess is that it has to do something with the case

Comment: One confusion here how 4th is bigger than 3rd? on which attribute you are assuming this?

Comment: notice that it's not the same case, it's not 'd' and 'i' , it's 'd' and 'I'....  I also added a link that verifies the order of my list, so 4th is the biggest

Comment: I tried to sort your list again and I think your 3rd and 4th key are in wrong order 4th is 3rd and 3rd should be placed on 4th thats why the only 3,4 key comparison is giving the -1  
https://onlinetoolz.net/alphabetical-order#list=-MmPtIJ1LpFTRbweNWvD%0A-MmPtd0IMuNIEYaPYPgZ&sort=0&reverse=0&show=3
try this link for sort

Comment: What algorithm do you use to sort your list? I tried it [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MwkQ7O) but in my case the `third` value is the biggest - that is also valid for using `OrdinalIgnoreCase`. The sample code also shows the byte-codes for each char that explains the order. BTW: Why is `I` (capital `i`) _smaller_ than `d`?

Comment: @ashhadullah and sebastian, your sorting methods ignore Upper case and Lower case. Use this link instead - https://onlinestringtools.com/sort-strings

Comment: By the way,  my list is sorted by Google Firebase Datebase , it stores the keys in my DB in alphabetical order, 1st,2nd,3rd,4th, while the 4th is the newest key I added to my DB and Google made sure it's bigger than the old keys. So this is how google sort the key of lists, and I also gave you a random link that sorts the strings

Comment: @SHAI Yes - that's right. If you use `StringComparison.Ordinal` it produces the result you want. But if you want that result you also need to use `string.Compare(x, y, StringComparison.Ordinal)` to get the expected result. See [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7owDLA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you actually want to sort these strings by their ordinal value (their binary representation). In that case use  `StringComparison.Ordinal` as comparisonType.

```
 string.Compare(third, fourth, StringComparison.Ordinal)); //output: -27
 string.Compare(second, third, StringComparison.Ordinal)); //output: -1
 string.Compare(first, second, StringComparison.Ordinal)); //output: -1
```

Weirdly the first comparison yields -27 instead of -1. The  Compare method only specifies that the return value will be <1, 0 or >1 so those three output are essentially (and semantically)  the same result.

Comment: Thanks I tried that and was worried by the -27

Comment: As for return value, it's ok and completely expected to be just a negative value, as was said [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.compare?view=net-5.0#remarks)

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting phenomenon that is likely caused by .NET performing a word-sort comparison, using weighted sorting rules to keep similar words together ([see remarks here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.compareoptions?view=net-5.0#remarks)).

It causes some interesting, if unexpected, results. Even when case-sensitivity is `false`:

```
string.Compare("A", "c", false); // -1
string.Compare("a", "c", false); // -1
string.Compare("E", "c", false); // 1
string.Compare("e", "c", false); // 1
```

For strict comparison that uses the character code ordering, you want to use an `Ordinal` comparison method.

```
// UPPERCASE letters come before lowercase.
string.Compare("A", "c", StringComparison.Ordinal); // -34
string.Compare("a", "c", StringComparison.Ordinal); // -2
string.Compare("E", "c", StringComparison.Ordinal); // -30
string.Compare("e", "c", StringComparison.Ordinal); // 2
```

Comment: "weighted sorting rules to keep similar words together" is not true, it's simply local culture sorting which makes certain sets of code points equivalent. Case insensitive is a specific part of that, where upper and lower case letters are considered equal. This is not some kind of fuzzy matching with words

Comment: @Charlieface It sorta gets fuzzy when we start getting into non-alphanumeric, no? Especially when they say they try to keep co-op and coop close. Edit: Not to mention the whole 20MB of downloadable "Sorting weight Table".

Comment: No there is simply no fuzziness here at all. Every culture has case-sensitive and insensitive sorts (and in some case diacritic-insensitive also), these have specific rules about which characters (and sometimes more than one character) are considered the same and in which order to sort. For example, ß and ss are the same in German, but not in English. ỻ and ll are equivalent in Welsh but not in English. Or what I'm trying to say: it's not doing Soundex or Levenshtein comparisons by whole words, it's just a comparison based on equivalent characters